# Валидация пароля Regex

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, валидация, password

Не могу написать код используя regex. Всё перепробовал. Надо, чтобы можно было использовать a-z A-Z 0-9 и только. Самое главное, чтобы не было пробела в пароле.

```
   if (entity.getPassword().matches(".*\\S.*")) {
        throw new ValidationException("Password cannot contain whitespace");
    }

    if (entity.getPassword().matches("\\w")) {
        throw new ValidationException("Password can contain only a-z A-Z 0-9");
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки на наличие пробельных символов нужно использовать класс `\s`, а не противоположный `\S`:

```java
if (entity.getPassword().matches(".*\\s.*")) {
    throw new ValidationException("Password cannot contain whitespace");
}
```

Впрочем, эта проверка лишняя, если в пароле разрешены только буквы/цифры.
Также стоит добавить проверку на минимальную длину пароля.

```java
if (!entity.getPassword().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}")) {
    throw new ValidationException("Password can contain only a-z A-Z 0-9");
}
```

Можно также добавить требования, чтобы были как минимум одна прописная, одна строчная, одна цифра:

```java
if (!entity.getPassword().matches("(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{6,}")) {
    throw new ValidationException("Password has to contain at least one capital letter, one small letter, one digit with the minimal length of 6");
}
```

Comment: мне надо чисто так как я написал. Чтобы разрешённые символы были и не было пробела

Comment: Добавил исправленную проверку на пробел, однако, если _сначала_ выполняется проверка на разрешённые символы, то проверка на пробел полностью бессмысленна.  Кроме того, если запрещён _только_ пробел, а не любые пробельные символы, можно использовать метод `String::contains` без всяких регулярных выражений: `if (password.contains(" "))`

Answer (score 0):

Проще пойти от обратного:

```
if(password.matches("[^a-zA-Z\\d]")) {
    throw new ValidationException("Password can contains only a-z A-Z 0-9 without whitespace");
}
```

Чтобы понять как работает этот шаблон, гугли:

1. Что такое набор символов в регулярных выражениях
2. Как инвертировать набор символов
3. Слияние диапазонов символов